# Differences between F.relu(X) and torch.max(X, 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement the following [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_loss)

[image]

To me, the most straight forword implementation would be using `torch.max`

```
losses = torch.max(ap_distances - an_distances + margin, torch.Tensor([0]))
```

However, I saw other [implementations on github](https://github.com/adambielski/siamese-triplet/blob/master/losses.py) using `F.relu`

```
losses = F.relu(ap_distances - an_distances + margin)
```

They give essential the same output, but I wonder if there's any fundamental difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 3):

`torch.max` is not differentiable according to this [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/got-no-graph-nodes-that-require-computing-gradients-when-use-torch-max/7952/2).
A loss function needs to be continuous and differentiable to do backprop. `relu` is differentiable as it can be approximated and hence the use of it in a loss function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to limit the output value like in ReLU6 (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ReLU6.html), you can use

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

x1 = F.hardtanh(x, min_value, max_value)
```

This preserves the differentiability of the model.
This will produce a result like below. (min and max values will be different)

[image: Relu6]